# c++ reference function parameter seems to contain a copy of the original object, not acts as a "real reference"

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

sorry for the newbie question. :)

the reference function parameter is connected to an object, but a modification on the reference has no effect to the original object.

Simplyfied code:

```
struct dummy{
    int i;
};
dummy arr[4];

// fill array
for(int n=0;n<4;n++){
    arr[n].i = n;
}

void foo(dummy& d){
    d = arr[0];// d.i == 0, so far so good
    d.i += 10; // d.i == 10, but arr[0] is still 0
}

...

dummy p;
foo(p);
p.i += 5; // p.i == 15, but arr[0] is still 0
```

If i use int instead of dummy, it is clear that the original won't change. But if just a property of an object is changed (object is still the same), i assume that the modification was made on the original object. 
But not. It seems that d = arr[0]; is just a copy.
Why?

I know, that this scenario can be done with pointers: void foo(dummy** d){...} but i wonder the reason of this reference behavior. A reference is "real" if it is defined in classic way: dummy &a=arr[0], but as function parameter: no.

Comment: do you want p to refer to arr[0]? in that case you need `dummy& p = arr[0];`

Comment: `p` and `arr` are different objects, so changing one should not change the other. References make no difference to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think your misunderstanding is over the line

```
d = arr[0];
```

You think that makes `d` refer to `arr[0]` but it doesn't. Instead it assigns `arr[0]` to whatever `d` is referring to.

In C++, once a reference has been *bound* it cannot be rebound. Any attempt to assign to a reference always assigns to what the reference is refering to, it never makes the reference refer to something else.

Comment: thanks, it was very fast answer. :) Summary: "reference parameter" is absolutely not equal to "reference" (when you bound it at definition to an object).

Comment: A reference parameter gets bound each time the function is called. Otherwise it behaves exactly the same as any other reference.

Answer (score 0):

Once initialized references cannot be rebound. The reference `d` in the function refers to the `dummy p` that you use to call the function. When you write

```
d = arr[0];
```

...that does not make `d` refer to `arr[0]`. Instead it assigns `arr[0]` to `p`. In other words, it makes a copy.